# Magento 2 get contact-us-info url in admin static block/page?

Tags: magento2, backend

how to `contact-us-info` url add in **cms static block** in admin

Screen shot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="{{store url="contact-us-info"}}">contacts</a>
```

Comment: I already tried it but not works  its gives https://prnt.sc/mfk7d7

Comment: add this code in static block

Comment: i was add this code https://prnt.sc/mfk969  but its not work

Comment: @divyasekar please check url-rerites in admin and check contact us page url

Comment: @divyasekar please check my answer if it is working please accpet.

Comment: I already upvote to your answer @hlren kadivar

Comment: please check my answer only accpet not upvote

Comment: check the screenshot https://prnt.sc/mhtsji @Hlren

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new link to the footer  links block. To do this, you need to add the

```
<li><a href="{{store url="contact-us-info"}}your page URL key">The link label</a></li> line before the </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create cms page and this static block call in cms page below way

```
{{block class="Magento\\Cms\\Block\\Block" block_id="contact-us-info"}}
```

and cms page url name give to  `contact-us-info`

after check it

Comment: I already tried it but not works its gives prnt.sc/mfk7d7

Comment: please add code share me screenshot

Comment: contact us link  [link](https://prnt.sc/mfk969) @rakesh and cms contact block  [link](https://prnt.sc/mfk9mc)

Comment: i got it your problem  static block identifier is not calling in `store url` so yoo can call in cms page url here

Comment: How to call in cms page url @rakesh

Comment: @divyasekar this answer is not work for you?